# Editing a question with multiple levels and paragraphs of block quotes broke the formatting

Tags: bug, edits

[This question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/51250/taranika-akroan-veterans-ability/51251#51251) previously looked like this

[image: Answer formatting before edit]

(Google cache version because I don't expect a rollback to fix it)

After editing the answer to change a single number, it now looks like this (cut off because that's how much of the page I could see):

[image: Answer formatting after edit]

Comment: The linked duplicate question says that block quote rendering has been modified so that separate paragraphs in block quotes are only rendered in a connected block quote if the normally blank lines in between have `>` symbols at the beginning. That was the problem here.